# How to automatically add space between digits as they are being entered into a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

We have pin numbers in the following format:

45 674 25 910

Our original requirement was to give the users the ability to enter their pin with or without spaces,

In other words, if the pin is 10 digits without spaces, we would like to accept it as valid input.

Similarly, if the pin is 13 digits (with the three spaces) we would also like to accept the input as valid.

If the digits are less than 10 with or without spaces, or more than 13 with spaces, we would like to throw an error that input is invalid.

The script below satisfied the above requirements:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            var result = true;
            if ($('#pin').val().replace(/ /g, '').length == 10) {
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
                alert("Invalid");
                return false;
            }
            return result;
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, management has decided to change the requirement to ask that spaces be automatically added while the user is entering the pin numbers.

In other words, users can enter the pin numbers with spaces or they can enter the pin numbers without spaces but that spaces be automatically added while they are typing the pin numbers.

Any ideas how to modify the script above?

Better yet, is there an example that I can modify to meet our requirements?

Comment: A good compromise is to be less constrictive with the string size and the spaces, and to check it once you have removed all the whitespaces. You can then change the format when the input box looses the focus.

Comment: try plugins for masking. there are quite a few.

Comment: The simplest form of validation could be to get the whole string all at once and then filter out the white spaces and whatnot to see if you are left with required number of digits. However a more clever way to do this would be utilizing the [`element.onkeyup()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event listener per digit entry.

Comment: @Redu, that's what the code I posted was doing. Then I was using SQL Replace function to add back the spaces to appear as the example format I posted.

Comment: As i have briefly mentioned, in order to fulfill the new requirement of the management (spaces to be automatically added while the user is entering the pin numbers), i would approach `element.onkeyup` event listener. I would check every entered single character to see if it is a number digit and would concatenate it to the value of `#pin`. However if the length of the current value is 2, 6 or 9 i would add the entered digit followed with a white space. Sorry i don't use JQuery. Pure JS is more than sufficient for all these jobs for my use cases.

Comment: @Redu - Does onkeyup get called for navigation and/or backspace, delete keys, or is the navigation handled transparently ? And like ctrl-c/x/v or that stuff ?

Comment: @Redu, can I see example in pure js?

Comment: Sorry, I live @ GMT +2. Anyways.. i suppose you may proceed with a solution given in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

***Note: this code will add space after 2, 3, 2, 3 ..etc  chars. you can change the number of chars by edit the code inside map***

```js
$("#user-input").on('keyup', function () {
     // Helpers
     var swap = 4, // Swap between 3 and 4
         index = 2; // Spaces indexs 2, 6, 9, 13 .. etc
    // This variable contains the same input value with sapces
    var niceVal = $(this).val()
        .replace("/\s/g", "").split("") // Remove all spaces and convert to array
        .map(function (item, i) { // loop throw the array
            if (i === 0) {
            return item;
        }
        if (i % index === 0) {
            item = item === " "
                ? item
                : " " + item;
            index += swap;
            swap = swap === 3
                ? 4
                : 3;
        }
            return item;
        }).join(""); // Convert array to string
    $(this).val(niceVal); // Update input value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="user-input">
```

Comment: thanks but per my requirement, shown here again, 45 674 25 910, it two digits then space, then 3 digits then space, then two digits then space, then three digits. They do not want it to work any other way.

Comment: @Kenny Updated!, Check it please.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is very, very close. The only issue now is that it won't stop at the last number. For instance, here is the data again:

45 674 25 910

Users can only enter 10 digits, not more, not less.

With your example, users can just keep entering digits until they run out of space.

I don't want to add MaxLength attribute because as stated at beginning, users can enter the digits with or without spaces.

Again, many thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Well with pure JS my approach to the problem could be as follows;

Though i mentioned the `keyup` event in my comment, it seems the `keydown` event turns out to be more appropriate since `keyup` might result a strange behavior when multiple keys are pressed at the same time due to speed typing. I haven't tested this thoroughly so it's just a guidance for you. However, if you discover any buggers i can possibly have a look into it.

**Edit:** Despite all my efforts I have come to the awareness of the fact that if you want to modify the value of an input element, like in this question, you must set up a logic to utilize both `keydown` and `keyup` events in a harmony. This will simplify your logic enormously and would yield a much sturdy code.

OK lets go...

```js
var pin = document.getElementById("PIN"),
    pbt = document.getElementById("PBT");

pin.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
                                  var val = e.target.value,
                                      len = val.length,
                                      lst = val[len-1],
                                      key = e.key;
                                  e.target.value = key === "Backspace" ? len === 4 ||
                                                                         len === 8 ||
                                                                         len === 11 ? val.slice(0,-1)
                                                                                    : val
                                                                       : len === 2 ||
                                                                         len === 6 ||
                                                                         len === 9  ? val + "\xa0"
                                                                                    : val;
                                });

pin.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
                                var val = e.target.value,
                                    pix = val.search(/[^0-9\xa0]/); // problem index
                                e.target.value = ~pix ? val.slice(0, pix) : val 
                              });

pbt.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                                pin.value.length === 13 ? console.log(pin.value)
                                                        : console.log("Please complete the PIN Code");
                              });
```

```html
<input id="PIN" value="" placeholder="Enter PIN" maxlength=13 size=13/>
<button id="PBT">Enter PIN</button>
```

Comment: thanks so much.

I am still trying to figure out why it won't work when integrated with my code.

I keep getting: `Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @Kenny I did some slight modification so that the Backspace key is working much better now. But honestly, if i would do this for a web site my choice would be to arrange 4 separate input elements with `mexlength` attributes 2, 3, 2 and 3 respectively. I guess that would be simpler to implement and more elegant.